# How to skip to next line in an ofstream object in c++

Tags: c++, file, hash, fstream, ostream

I'm trying to make a hash program that makes hashes for you. I know it's been done before but I'm trying to recreate it. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to add logs for each hash and output it to a "DataLog.txt" file. So far it's going Great! The only problem is that I'm trying to add a newline before each output to the text file. At the moment it writes it to the text file, then when it repeats to write again it just overlaps the previous writing. This is the code I have for the file outputting so far.

```
     std::ofstream file;
        file.open("DataLog (2).txt");
        file << input << hash;
        file.close();
```

The entire main function I have is also listed below. It might be a little long so get ready.

```
int main() {
    
    while (1) {
        std::cout << "Welcome to SHA256 Generator! Please enter the string you would like to convert to a hash:" << std::endl;
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cout << "Hash - " << sha256(input);
        auto hash = ConvertToString(sha256(input));

        std::ofstream file;
        file.open("DataLog (2).txt");
        file << input << hash;
        file.close();
        
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Would you like to convert another hash? Please enter either yes or no for your respose." << std::endl;
        std::string response;
        std::cin >> response;
        if (response == "no")
            return 0;
        while (response != "yes" ) {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Sorry I didn't get that. Can you try typing either yes or no again?" << std::endl;
            std::string responseRepeat;
            std::cin >> responseRepeat;     
            if (responseRepeat == "yes" || responseRepeat == "no") {
                clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Open file in append mode.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: just add `ios::app` as a second parameter when you open the file.

Comment: It sort of worked but not in the way I wanted to be honest. It doesn't overlap the previous text anymore, but how do I make it print to the next line? I don't think I can use std::endl or \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see, you want to add a line before each line. I think what you are looking for lies in `file << input << hash;`

So since `file` is your fstream output, you can treat it like `cout`. So the solution here would be `file << input << hash << endl;`

Now also make sure to open file in append mode by `file.open(filename, ios::app);` if you dont want your text to override.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it before with endl and \n, but it did just as you said and overlapped the previous one.